# Dyson's lemma implies index is small (in proving Roth's theorem)

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation, diophantine-geometry

I am reading the proof of Roth's theorem in Hindry-Silverman's book. In there they used Roth's lemma. I think it is well known that the step of Roth's lemma could be replaced by Dyson's lemma to show the index is small. I wonder how to do it in details.

So I found the [notes by Nakamaye](https://mast.queensu.ca/%7Emikeroth/proceedings/Nakamaye-Roth-Method.pdf), the set up is
[image]

and Dyson's lemma says that
[image]

The discussion in the notes:
[image]
I am confused about

1. what is this $\beta$?
2. I don't understand the purpose of condition $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]\text{Vol}(\beta)=1-\gamma$.
3. why there is a condition of height bounded (and seems in Roth's lemma there is a similar condition)?

I guess I don't understand the process of transferring the Vol bound to the index bound. If there is a detailed argument it would be great.

This question is also posted on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539900/dysons-lemma-implies-index-is-small-in-proving-roths-theorem).